# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081 in postman

Tags: postman, mulesoft

I have a created a flow in the Mulesoft's Anypoint platform with the HTTP listener and now trying to test the flow by exposing that API through postman locally.

Below is the messgae from error console

```
GET http://localhost:8081/test
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 92ca3330-3dd3-4bfc-a183-f3cb4f22f469
Host: localhost:8081
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Understood a bit that some proxy settings and made those changes but still couldn't resolve this

Comment: When you say created a flow in Anypoint Platform do you mean in the cloud (CloudHub) or locally (Anypoint Studio IDE)?

Comment: If you are not getting an actual HTTP response, then it is a proxy issue. If you ARE, then it could be a protocol issue: ex. Using HTTP when the server is expecting HTTPS.

Comment: @aled I created the flow locally

Comment: Then you are not deploying to Anypoint Platform, and no proxy should be required for a local call, unless there is a firewall in your development machine. Please share the XML of the of the flow as text (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Are you using the correct HTTP method?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same warning from postman, I later found that
i was excluding port in my setting.

It will be nice if you include your code, but you can use the below setup...

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.post("/users", (req, res) => {
    res.send("testing...")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running at port ", port);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With absence of source file/snapshot, couple of things to look at:

1. Please check in your local mule Configuration file contains *API Auto Discovery* and is enabled, Comment it out and try again.
   RCA: if this config is enabled then even local request is first redirecting to API manager who is not approving your connection request.
   Ps: Remember to un-comment before committing
2. Verify the port number is correct
   RCA: sometimes port number is provided different
3. Verify host for the listener is configured to localhost
   RCA: sometimes host is set different
4. Check if right configuration file is being read for listener.
   RCA: Maybe in config global variable maybe set dev instead of local hence dev properties are being read instead of local.