# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.233.41.18:443

Tags: postman, mule

The application Anypoint Studio and runtime got deployed fine, but when I am testing with Postman I am getting this error

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.233.41.22
Could you guys help, please?

Comment: Hi, you will need to provide more details about what port and protocol is the application listening, where is it deployed, if you were able to test it in some other way (it is not clear from the question). Ideally share the XML (as text, no screenshots) configuration of the connector you are  using in the Mule application. Did you execute inside Anypoint Studio only, or also in a standalone Mule runtime?

Comment: please add postman screenshot , url etc

Answer (score 0):

This probably points to the application not running on the port described. Is it 8082 perhaps? Based on https://developer.mulesoft.com/tutorials-and-howtos/getting-started/how-to-setup-https-anypoint-studio.

Answer (score 0):

With not much input here, similar case I've answered a while back please check it out here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68324986/16418253